# Картинка отправляется не с прозрачным фоном, а с белым

Tags: python, aiogram

```
photo = InputFile("photo.png")
await bot.send_photo(chat_id=callback.from_user.id,
                     photo=photo,
                     caption="...",
                     reply_markup=markup)
```

Картинка отправляется не с прозрачным фоном, а с белым. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Никак. Видимо телега не поддерживает прозрачность для фоток

Comment: Чтоб стикеры покупали)))

Answer (score 0):

фотки не могут отправляться с прозрачным фоном, только стикеры могут быть с прозрачным фоном.